# Extract a Drools Guvnor .pkg file

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

I am new to Drools and to Guvnor. We have created DRL file and loaded in Guvnor and we got the package built. It has resulted in a `.pkg` file. We download this `.pkg` file from Guvnor and use it for our different projects. Now I am trying to see things inside the `.pkg` file, but I am not sure how to open this.

Comment: Your Drools version is...? What exactly are you trying to "see" in the PKG file, and why? It doesn't contain anything that isn't in your DRL file, but getting *all* of that is no easy task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code examines a knowledge base and will write out the names of all the packages that were loaded into it and the names of the rules in those packages. There's probably a bit more info that can be extracted, but I have never found the need. The only thing you won't get is the source code of the rules. But going by your explanation, that is available in Guvnor.

```
/**
 * Return a string containing the packages used to build the knowledge base.
 */
public static String knowledgeBaseDetails(KieBase kbase) {
    if (kbase == null) {
        return "Knowledge Base is null.";
    } else {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "Knowledge base built from the following packages:");
        Collection<KiePackage> packages = kbase
                .getKiePackages();
        for (KiePackage kp : packages) {
            sb.append("\n    Package: [" + kp.getName() + "]");
            for (Rule rule : kp.getRules()) {
                sb.append("\n        Rule: [" + rule.getName() + "]");
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

It's almost the same for Drools 5 and 6. Generally for the earlier versions of Drools, just change `Kie` to `Knowledge`.

Comment: Thanks for your code, good to know I can get information of DRL that is deployed programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tool (that I'm aware of) for opening a Drools pkg file and inspect its content. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, a possible solution would be to programatically create a Kiebase (or kbase) from that pkg and programatically inspect its content.

By the way, what are you trying to find inside that file?

Hope it helps,

Comment: Sure good to know,there ain't tools available.Just to see what is in it, In our project drl is created by BA's and is given to us as a .pkg file.